# 4 students are less

Tags: word-usage, usage

4 students were still not on the bus, when our school was about to leave the school (when school let out). I know that one way of expressing this is:

> 4 students aren't here yet.

But after counting the number of students on the bus, can this be used:

> 4 students are **less**.

What about:

> 4 students are **short.**
>
> 4 students are **missing**.

I think the third one sound really weird....

Answer (score 2):

You need to think what you are predicating it of.

If you are talking about *short*, it is the group that is short, not the students that are late (or even the group of late students), so you can say:

> We are four students short (or "We are short of four students"),

but you can't say that the students are short with that meaning.

The same for *less*, except that there needs to be something to compare with, so

> We are four students less than we were expecting. (Though *we have* would be more natural there); but you can't say that the students are less, with that meaning.

*Missing* is a different case. It is an adjective, meaning "not there, when expected". So

> Four students are missing.

is exactly what you mean.

Comment: ***Short*** is sometimes a bit odd (I'm not even sure if syntactically it's all the same whether you're being *given **short shrift*** or ***short measure***). But I certainly can't explain why [*If **there is an ounce short** they discover it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22there+is+an+ounce+short%22) sounds fine, whereas ***An ounce is short*** just sounds completely weird.

Answer (score 0):

> 4 students are missing.

This one is grammatically fine.

> 4 students are short.

This is describing the students as short (opposite of tall), not describing the number of students as short.  You could say "We are 4 students short [of the expected number]".

> 4 students are less.

Less than what?  No, that can't be used.  You could say "We have 4 students less than we expected".

Comment: So the likely ones are "We are four students short", "Four students are not here yet", "Four students are missing". What sounds the best out of these three?